# Create junction from subdirectory or root?

Tags: windows, ntfs, ntfs-junction

If a user wanted to create a junction from, say, C:\Users\username\Pictures\MyTrip to E:\MyTrip, is there any practical difference between creating the junction from the root of C:\ or from the path: "C:\Users\username\Pictures\"? i.e.:
`C:\> mklink Users\username\Pictures\MyTrip E:\MyTrip /j`
 vs 
`C:\Users\username\Pictures> mklink MyTrip E:\MyTrip /j`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only differences I can think of is,

1) The permissions will be set (default to) the actual location. For instance, if the target/source directory is located at C:\, the directory itself and it's contents will have the permissions of any directory at the root of the drive - tightened security. <-- I think..

2) In File Explorer (and most file management tools I'm familiar with, such as Total Commander), if you delete the junction only the junction (reparse-point) is deleted - not the files within. While if you delete the junction's target/source, the entire directory and everything it contains is deleted. <-- I know.. :)

If it makes any difference, and perhaps a third point, I always keep the "real" directories in my user directory and create junctions pointing to those from other locations, such as C:\Bin --> C:\Users\Me\Bin. I do this to make it easier to backup all of my data, because I know everything important is *always* in my user directory.